# Adding a column to a table with a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to replace a column in an existing table (product table) from a category, to a productCategoryID which is also a primary key, from the ProductCategory table. I've pasted my progress so far, but am stuck.

```
alter table product
Add ProductCategoryID smallint
constraint PK_ProductCategory Primary Key (ProductCategoryID)
references ProductCategory(ProductCategoryID)
```

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Idea of ProductCategory as the name suggests does not mean it will be unique in your case... So it might not be the right candidate for PK for Product table

Comment: What you are stuck? Does already Product table has a PK? What is your error?

Comment: You need to first add the column in one statement then add the constraints in another using alter table and add constraint (except if you use PRIMARY KEY when creating the column, it will automatically create the constraint). I would look at the MS docs syntax this should be pretty simple for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to first add a column. Then you can add a constraint to the table. These steps can't be slammed together. And your notion of a primary key referencing a column in another table makes no sense. That is a foreign key. I suspect you want something along these lines.

```
alter table product
Add ProductCategoryID smallint

alter table product
add constraint FK_ProductCategory Foreign Key (ProductCategoryID)
references ProductCategory(ProductCategoryID)
```

Comment: They can be "slammed together". `alter table product
Add ProductCategoryID smallint, constraint FK_ProductCategory Foreign Key (ProductCategoryID)
references ProductCategory(ProductCategoryID)`

Comment: Appreciate the help @Sean Lange. I tested your suggestion, but any idea why my ProductCategoryID is returning NULL values instead of the ID number it's referencing?  Thanks again mate.

Comment: Did you insert any values into that column in the product table?